Python Web Scraping Selenium+BeautifulSoup with gspread and Google Sheets problem with big amounts of data
I am making a web scraper that scrapes all of the data from this page with around 1500 products.
I am extracting the name of the item, if it is a best seller, what kind of type of clothing it is, how many colours are available and the price of the item. Everything is extracted on the same link with BeautifulSoup.
for item in items:
    name = item.find('a', class_ = 'product-card__link-overlay').text.strip()
    try:
        special_tag = item.find('div', class_ = 'product-card__messaging accent--color').text.strip()
    except:
        special_tag = '/'
    productclass = item.find('div', class_ = 'product-card__subtitle').text.strip()
    colours = item.find('div', class_ = 'product-card__product-count').text.strip()
    try:
        price = item.find('div', class_ = 'product-price us__styling is--current-price css-11s12ax').text.strip()
    except:
        price = item.find('div', class_ = 'product-price is--current-price css-1ydfahe').text.strip()
    product = {'name':name, 'special':special_tag, 'class':productclass, 'colours':colours, 'price':price}
    sh.append_row([str(product['name']),str(product['special']),str(product['class']),str(product['colours']),str(product['price'])]) 

To be able to extract everything I used Selenium to scroll through the whole page and load it in its entirety.
time.sleep(3)
previous_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')

while True:
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')

    time.sleep(3)

    new_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')

    if new_height == previous_height:
        page_source = driver.page_source
        break    
    previous_height = new_height   

After I extract the page source and use it in BeautifulSoup and there appears to be a problem. I tried every single thing, even researched on internet I could think of and it still did not work. The program only extracts about 65-70 products and the suddenly stops.
Whole code just for reference:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import gspread
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open('Nike catalog').sheet1


driver.get('https://www.nike.com/w/mens-clothing-6ymx6znik1')

#Scroll program
time.sleep(3)
previous_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')

while True:
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')

    time.sleep(3)

    new_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')

    if new_height == previous_height:
        page_source = driver.page_source
        break    
    previous_height = new_height   


#Main program
baseurl='https://www.nike.com/w/mens-clothing-6ymx6znik1'

headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

soup = BeautifulSoup( page_source,'lxml')

items = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'product-card__body')

#HTML parser
for item in items:
    name = item.find('a', class_ = 'product-card__link-overlay').text.strip()
    try:
        special_tag = item.find('div', class_ = 'product-card__messaging accent--color').text.strip()
    except:
        special_tag = '/'
    productclass = item.find('div', class_ = 'product-card__subtitle').text.strip()
    colours = item.find('div', class_ = 'product-card__product-count').text.strip()
    try:
        price = item.find('div', class_ = 'product-price us__styling is--current-price css-11s12ax').text.strip()
    except:
        price = item.find('div', class_ = 'product-price is--current-price css-1ydfahe').text.strip()
    product = {'name':name, 'special':special_tag, 'class':productclass, 'colours':colours, 'price':price}
    sh.append_row([str(product['name']),str(product['special']),str(product['class']),str(product['colours']),str(product['price'])]) 



I went through the entire loaded page and made myself sure that the HTML classes and code was the same for each of the products. Maybe it is some kind of ban that Nike has integrated in their website, I do not use any proxies. I also made sure to pass through exceptions and it did not work.
I do not know how I could fix this. Did anybody encounter the same problem or has experience in something like this? If you do it would be greatly appreciated if you could solve it. Thanks in advance.

Has it occurred to you that you might be getting blocked?

It is possible, but I do not know how to check. Hadn't happened to me yet. Do you know how I can bypass that?

While testing this with my program, I observed that the loading of the 'cards' stopped at the point where cards stock reached 48. That case was when PAGE_DOWN operation was set to 10 times every 3 seconds. So it seems that loading stops if we reach bottom of the view before new cards are loaded.
Timing set in the following test program is assured effective. It takes about 10 minutes.
import lxml.html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from datetime import  datetime

start_time = datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
url='https://www.nike.com/w/mens-clothing-6ymx6znik1'

driver.get(url)

card_num_elm= WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='wall-header__content']/h1/span")))
card_num = int(card_num_elm.text.strip('()'))
print('\ntop expression: ',card_num,'\n' )

#load more by scrolling down
pre_count = 0
same_count_times = 0
for i in range(150):
    
    for pd in range(4):
        actions.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()
        sleep(1)
    sleep(2)
    cards= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-card__body']")))

    new_count = len(cards)
    print('len(cards): ',new_count)

    #if new_count >= card_num-1:
        #break
    if new_count == pre_count:
        same_count_times += 1
    else:
        same_count_times = 0
    pre_count = new_count
    if same_count_times > 3:
        break

#get whole html (by Selenium)　
page = driver.page_source 
    
#transfer to lxml
p_root = lxml.html.fromstring(page)
    
list_elements = p_root.xpath("//div[@class='product-card__body']") 
new_count = len(list_elements)
print('\nnumber on the lxml: ',new_count)
    
print ('\nstarted at : ', start_time )
print ('ended at   : ', datetime.today().strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ,'\n')


Hey, thank you so much for responding. I will gladly try this code out I just cannot seem to understand if I can still use BeautifulSoup to parse it or it needs some kind of other method. If you could explain I would be very grateful.

Of course you can use BeautifulSoup instead of lxml, after driver.page_saurce.
